# mysql query using 'OR' syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Simple mysql question i am trying to write a query based on a criteria of four values however it does not seem to be working, here is and example of the query:

```
select * from table_1 where c=0 d=0 a=0 u=0 or c=1 d=1 a=1 u=1
```

Comment: My immediate response would be: select * from table_1 where (c=0 and d=0 and a=0 and u=0) or (c=1 and d=1 and a=1 and u=1) but that seems too easy...

Comment: It seems that you are not familiar with basic SQL grammar.

Comment: Thank you, I do not see any question as silly, the only silly question is the one not asked so me being a learner i do not see where the question had to be down rated, however I do thank you all for the help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `WHERE` logic is incorrect:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where (c=0 and d=0 and a=0 and u=0) 
or (c=1 and d=1 and a=1 and u=1)
```

You need to group your statements together in parenthesis and still use `AND` for any conditions that need to be grouped together.

Comment: Parens may be a good practice, but there were not strictly necessary here because AND has precedence over OR.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if these are always 0 and 1, you can use a trick to shorten the query:

```
where c+d+a+u = 0 or c*d*a*u = 1
```